# Where are stored Bluetooth devices information connected to a PC?

Tags: windows, file, bluetooth, device

I have some devices charged on a computer via Bluetooth, but I need to add those devices to more than 150 computers more.

I would want to know, where are stored these Bluetooth devices I have already added on the pc, to copy the file in all other computers and save lots of hours of work. In this way, I could do it in less than a minute.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean: **pairing** Bluetooth devices ?

if so, you need to do it manually to all 150 computers...

Comment: Yes. But somewhere on computer must be stored this data, I suppose, right?

Comment: When I make an image from a computer and I put it on another, these pairing Bluetooth devices get saved, this means this information is stored somewhere on computer.

Comment: i understand, but you still need to pair the devices. your other Bluetooth device (ex. mobile phone, headset) will not accept the connection if you don't pair the 2 devices. (more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Pairing_mechanisms)

Comment: I want to see more opinions. Because as I said before, when I make an image of a computer and I put it on other computers, Bluetooth devices work on all computers without necesity of parirng any device again. Only one time. But this is also very slow. So there must be a method.

Comment: @Isdera: Unless all of your computers have the same hardware address (BD_ADDR), this probably won't work as you expect. What's the device? which bluetooth version does it support?